# update BigQuery schema with a RECORD field using Python API

Tags: python, google-bigquery

We are writing code to '*augment*' our BigQuery tables with additional metadata in an automated way by using the Python API

We do this by using the key-value labeling system (*works fine*), and updating the column descriptions by:

- Per table, iterate over the schema columns
- Do something with the column metadata
- Add the column to a new schema
- Update the schema

**However**, the **last** step gives an error when working with tables that having RECORD type fields. When trying to update the schema I receive the following error on the 1st nested field inside the RECORD field:

> SchemaField(u'nestedField', u'integer', u'NULLABLE', None, ()) is not
>   JSON serializable

The code looks like this:

```
orig_table = bigquery_client.get_table(table)
schema = list(orig_table.schema)

new_schema = list()

for column in schema:
        columntxt = *do something to define the column metadata* 

        new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(column.name, column.field_type, column.fields,  description=columntxt ))

orig_table.schema = new_schema
table = bigquery_client.update_table(orig_table, ['schema', 'labels'])
```

**How to properly resolve this / make the code work with nested schema tables?**

Comment: what is `bigquery_client` ? It's not clear from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you built your request is sending wrong parameters to `SchemaField` constructor (which in turn can't be encoded into JSON).

Try this instead:

```
for column in schema:
    columntxt = *do something to define the column metadata* 
    new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(
        column.name,
        column.field_type,
        fields=column.fields,
        description=columntxt,
        mode=column.mode))

orig_table.schema = new_schema
table = bigquery_client.update_table(orig_table, ['schema'])
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Even made it more explicit by coding:
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(name=column.name, field_type=column.field_type, fields=column.fields,  description=columntxt, mode=column.mode))

Comment: funny thing, if you do like that you might indicate for those reading your code that the method signature is made of keyworded arguments which might lead to some confusion. While this works, I suspect (still need to confirm that) that it's better to express positional arguments like so and only keyworded as you did, so there's no ambiguous interpretation of your code. Still, you can choose whatever fits your coding style best. Glad to know the answer worked :)

Comment: Willian, when it comes to Python coding, I still am a beginner. Therefore I do not fully understand your last remark. But as I like to learn: do you have any external reference that explains what you mean?

Comment: This [blog post](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314818) seems good enough. It's a few minutes read though but for learning these stuff it seems a good place to start.